# Readability-like JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, readability, instapaper

Is there a (client-side) JavaScript library for doing [Readability](http://www.readability.com/)/[Instapaper](http://instapaper.com)-style uncluttering of HTML? ie Takes HTML for a full web page and unclutters it by removing headings, sidebars etc, to just leave the core article, using some heuristics. I'm looking for something like *clean(htmlPageString)*.

I think readability itself is implemented in JavaScript, but there's no library for it.

Comment: you may want to re-word this entire question. I first assumed you were talking about code formatting (tidy) but in fact you want to have a 'print/read' view to all of your pages? but why do this in javascript - why not in a MVC 'View' and pretty it up with a lightbox or something .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is readability, encapsulated in a node module: [node-readability](https://github.com/luin/readability). It works fine, but not in every case. I am currently looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I think this JavaScript library is along the lines of what you are looking for. It is a standalone version of the library used to generate [Firefox's Reader View](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages).

https://github.com/mozilla/readability

Answer (score 0):

As per my reading, its built in javascript+JSON that stores the reading list of users in a queue in the form of JSON. It keeps track of the webpage requests along with time,date and some other specific information.